# Nginx failing on stress test

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I have been stress testing a new setup for my company's production environment, and have found that occasionally Nginx is failing under load.

We are using AWS as our cloud provider and a load balance sits in front of our nginx servers, who connect to an additional internal load balancer to send traffic to our PHP cluster for processing.

On load, the Nginx service fails silently (the only error we get is a 'An error has occurred' page) and there is nothing in the logs to advise what happened. On an 'nginx reload' the system returns to normal.

Has anyone come across this issue before, any ideas what might be causing it ?

Comment: Are you sure it's nginx that can't take the load and not your app servers? I've recently experience a similar issue where at 10, 000 concurrent connections per second, tested via [loader.io](https://loader.io/), I received 5xx errors. This was because the **app server** couldn't handle the load. Have you checked your [nginx amplify](https://amplify.nginx.com/dashboard) dashboard for info?

Comment: Thanks Keenan!

We do use loader.io, so it's definitely a possibility that the app servers are choking.

When I'm back in the office tomorrow, I'll set up amplify properly and see what I can dig up. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: If you're concerned about the number of connections and response time, consider deploying [varnish](http://varnish-cache.org) in front of nginx. This way, requests won't hit your app server after the first request. Take care in defining your caching policies though.  Good luck!

Comment: P.S I don't think New Relic picks up on the load test, so you can't check app server response times from a third party (although loader.io provides this for you)

Comment: Thanks Keenan!

Wish I could use Varnish... or any caching solution. Unfortunately Nginx fronts our API, so caching data is out of the question :(

But you were right.. it was the app servers choking. Thanks for the tips. Amplify is cool!

Comment: Ah, I see... Well, at least you know where the problem lies! :) All the best!